# PHP - Looping multiply elements

Tags: php, mysql, database, loops

I'm using looping for images on my list, but now I want to loop more elements - that is titles and descriptions.  How do I do that?

**Code**

```
mysql_select_db($database_connection, $connection);
$query_img = "SELECT imgname FROM img ORDER BY imgname";
$img = mysql_query($query_img, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_img = mysql_fetch_assoc($img);
$totalRows_img = mysql_num_rows($img);

$query_post = "SELECT title, description FROM post";
$post = mysql_query($query_post, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_post = mysql_fetch_assoc($post);
$totalRows_post = mysql_num_rows($post);


<ul>
    <?php
        while($row_img = mysql_fetch_assoc($img)) {
    ?>
        <li>
            <img src="images/<?php echo $row_img['imgname']; ?>">
            <h3><?php echo $row_post['title']; ?></h3>
            <p><?php echo $row_post['description']; ?></p>
        </li>
    <?php
    }
    ?>   

</ul>
```

Comment: where do you want to show these events. A separate unordered list?

Comment: The first move I'd make -- before any other fixes -- is to move away from plain mysql calls.  At a BARE minimum, use mysqli; better yet, upgrade to PDO.  There are some huge security and performance gains to be had, and the code can be written in a cleaner, easier to read manner.

Comment: how you you know which title and description belong to which image. How are the entries between the two tables related?

Comment: rather than making nested loops you'd probably be better to use a mySql `join` so that you have the image, description  and title all in the row

Comment: @rakeshjain no, in the same `ul` as the images. I have looped the images, but I don't know how to proceed if I want the titles and descriptions to be looped too

Comment: @rakeshjain there is a post entity with titles and description and it's connected to a image-entity witch stores image filenames as well as some other data

Comment: thats what I am asking about. What is the name of column that relates these two entities? There is a img_id column in post table or there is a post_id column in img table? Onc we know this, we can use a single join query to accomplish the task

Comment: there is no column that relates them, since each post can have only one image. sorry for not being precise. the imagename is the primary key in the image entity/table, while the post have post_id as primary keys. in the post entity there is imagename - FK that connects this entity with the image entity

Comment: Show us `show create table imgname;` and `show create table post;` output.

Comment: Why use the image name as your primary key? You can just insert `postID` column into your `image` table and then join both table or even have both table combined to have less joins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are many title, descriptions for every photo just put another while to the code above:

```
while($row_post = mysql_fetch_assoc($post)) {

echo "<h3>".$row_post['title']."</h3>";
echo "<p>".$row_post['description']."</p>";

}
```

I don't get what's the problem..
If it'll be just one title, desc. for every photo than better adjust your SQL query to fetch all of that at once.

**This is what you need:**

`SELECT * FROM image INNER JOIN post ON post.postimage = image.imagename;`

Create a view from it:

```
CREATE VIEW all_you_need AS <the_one_above>
```

and you can easy use it on PHP:

```
SELECT * FROM all_you_need;
```

**One more advice:**
Learn what MVC term means, what are benefits of that. You can build app your own way from scratch or at least use something for View (for example Smarty).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a second while loop for the rows associated with the post data, but what I think you really need (above and beyond migrating to PDO or at least mysqli methods) is to get the data together in one query.

Right at the moment, it looks like you're trying to display an image to go with each title and description; you'd have a better result if you merged the data into one query so that you can iterate over both data sets at the same time.  Otherwise, you're stuck hoping that you've got the right title and description to go with the image name you're serving.

Without knowing more about the underlying data structure, I'm not sure of the exact query you need but it's probably based on the JOIN syntax.